# Query mySQL to request number of category entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to display the number of entries in a mySQL table by their category `new`, `process`, `completed`.

Do I need to query (request) the table 3 times or is it possible to make one query only ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  `group by` is probably what you are looking for though... `select category, count(*) from yourtable  group by category` would be my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select category, count(*) as qty from yourtable group by category